# why override java's equals() method this way?

Tags: java, algorithm, equals

I try to override equals() method from Object class.

```
 @Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(this == o)
        return true; 
    if(!(o instanceof Menu))
       return false;
   Menu menu = (Menu)o; 
   return price == menu.price &&
          Objects.equals(name,menu.name); 
}
```

From what I learned,
if (this==o) is true , then true will be returned as a result of equals method. and the equals method will be stopped.

when people override equals method, they always put if(this == o) with returned value. but if the first if-statement is true , then other if-statement will not executed and other if-statement will not be checked

I don't know why people override equals() method in this way..
I would be really appreciated if someone helps me
I could not find the answer to this question..
Thank you so much !

Comment: the first if answer the question "am i equal to myself?"

Comment: It's not necessary but a performance thing. The reference check is faster than both the instanceof one and the actual equals invocation.

Comment: Thank you for the answers..(this == o) has return value which is 'true', so the equals() method will be stopped. and this method cant check other if-statement .. isnt it? because the method is stopped after returning 'true'?

Comment: Yes, the method is short circuited because of the `return`.

Comment: I have a more open vision of programming languages i don't use only java so equality between two pointers for me is still an equality check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects must compare equal to themselves. If you don't add this first check, it's surprisingly easy for an object to not compare equal to itself. Typically, this can happen if you have a `float` or `double` field.

For example, if `X` is a class with a double field `f`, then this code is WRONG, because it violates the reflexive rule of equality:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(!(o instanceof X))
       return false;
   X x = (X)o;
   return f == x.f;
}
```

If you compare an object with `f=Double.NaN` to itself, it will return false -- because NaN does not compare equal to itself.

Comment: @user16320675: that is in fact the case if the value is `NaN`. It's a specific value that's "not-a-number" and is defined to be equal to nothing (not even itself!).

Comment: @user16320675 https://ideone.com/OicCxv they're primitives. That is a property of NaN.

Comment: @JoachimSauer What you said is correct except that  NaN is not a specific value, it's a (surprisingly large) set of values.

Comment: @PaulHankin: I'm aware, I was (over-)simplifying it. But specifically for Java ["...  the Java SE Platform generally treats NaN values of a given floating-point type as though collapsed into a single canonical value ..."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3).

Answer (score 2):

Because if `this == o` it means that both `this` and `o` are actually the same object, so they are equal by definition and there's no need for further comparisons.

Comment: More formally, it ensures the "reflexive" requirement for implementations of [Object.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). It is not only unnecessary to perform further checks - returning false would actually break the contract.